# PDO two queries, one for found rows other for results?

Tags: php, mysql

I currently do two queries when using prepared statements.  One to fetch the results and another to fetch the number of found rows.  I could previously do this with one query with `mysql_num_rows`. With larger queries i don't want to have to copy and paste the query and use COUNT every query.  Is there a way to do this in one query like with `mysql_num_rows`?

```
 $connectdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
        $connectdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $query = $connectdb->execute(array(':username'=>$username));                                    
            $numrows = $query->fetchColumn();

             if($numrows!=0) {
               while(false !==($row = $query->fetch()))
               {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement already has the row count: [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

So use `$query->rowCount();` and your first query only

PS: your code doesn't look like it even would work. The correct one should be:

```
$stmt = $connectdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
$stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));                                    
...
```

Comment: i think rowcount is not for select queries.

Comment: @user892134: you think or you know? Have you checked the documentation link I gave?

Comment: yes it says "PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by a DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement. "

Comment: @user892134: have you tried to read further? There are more than just 1 paragraph ther

Comment: Yes for select queries it says "For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action. "

Comment: @user892134: for mysql it works. And your question is about mysql. What's wrong?

Comment: ok, so it works for mysql.  I assumed the documentation was referring to mysql databases.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query=$connectdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username");
    $query->execute(array(':username'=>$username));                                    
            $numrows = $query->rowCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have 3 options available in PDO:**

**1)** what you currently have, by using `COUNT()`:

```
$numrows = $query->fetchColumn();
```

**2)** `fetchColumn()` without executing the query itself:

```
$pdo->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from users")->fetchColumn();
```

**3)** `rowCount()` **NOTE** - apparently doesn't work in MySQL, and I don't recommend this:

```
PDOStatement::rowCount();
```

**EDIT** - To clarify - Number 3, this is a reference from the PDO Doc:

> For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.

Comment: "fetchColumn() without executing the query itself" -- this phrase is confusing. The query is executed before.

Comment: @random, not with SELECT statements.

Comment: Updated with PDO Doc reference, sorry for confusion.